# Apache NiFi not converting recognizing decimal type in convertJsontoAvro Processor

Tags: avro, apache-nifi, parquet

I have a **ConvertJsontoAvro** processor in NiFi 1.4 and am having difficulty getting the proper datatype of decimal within the avro. The data is being transformed into bytes using logical Avro data types within **ExecuteSQL** processor, converting avro to Json using **ConvertAvrotoJSON** processor, and then using **ConvertJsonToAvro** processor to put into HDFS using **PutParquet**.

My schema is :

> `{ "type" : "record", "name" : "schema", "fields" : [ { "name" : "entryDate", "type" : [ "null", { "type" : "long", "logicalType" : "timestamp-micros" } ], "default" : null }, { "name" : "points", "type" : [ "null", { "type" : "bytes", "logicalType" : "decimal", "precision" : 18, "scale" : 6 } ], "default" : null }] }`

My JSON:

> `{ "entryDate" : 2018-01-26T13:48:22.087, "points" : 6.000000 }`

I get an error for the avro saying

`Cannont convert field points: Cannot resolve union : {"bytes": "+|Ð" not in ["null", {"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":18,"scale":6}]"`

Is there some type of work around for this?...

Comment: If the end goal is to use PutParquet, why do you need to go from Avro to Json back to Avro? can't you send the Avro from ExecuteSQL directly to PutParquet?

Comment: It also might be worth using ConvertRecord instead of ConvertAvroToJson and ConvertJsonToAvro, those are the older style conversions and ConvertRecord is the new approach.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot mix null type and logical types due to bug in Avro. Check this still unresolved issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1891

Also the defaults value cannot be null. This should work for you:

```
{
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "schema",
    "fields" : [ {
      "name" : "entryDate",
      "type" : {
        "type" : "long",
        "logicalType" : "timestamp-micros"
      },
      "default" : 0
    }, {
      "name" : "points",
      "type" : {
        "type" : "bytes",
        "logicalType" : "decimal",
        "precision" : 18,
        "scale" : 6
      },
      "default" : ""
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I was able to set the decimal and a default value as null (in cases when the field is null or missing), currently using Nifi 1.14.0

```
{
  "name": "value",
  "type": [
    "null",
    {
      "type": "bytes",
      "logicalType": "decimal",
      "precision": 8,
      "scale": 4
    }
  ],
  "default": null
}
```